# Demo content not displaying on the website

Tags: magento2, theme

I use free template > http://www.templatemonster.com/magento-themes/57559.html#gref

The problem is, I installed after a long trouble and now I see only skeleton structure of the website(theme) and no images or nothing. Please take a look at  http://edatic.in/sergio

Please let me know what & how should I move further to display demo content.

Raj.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know about this theme but for other aspect these are the step you can take for theme integration

1) download fresh copy of magento( in your case only)

2) merge theme folder with your package

3) run sql from theme provider in your db

4) start magento installation and give db name where you install that sql file, and complete installation

and check everything is working

Hope this will help you